# Is there a way or tool to search or know, how many results does google fetch and display with lots of keywords?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, research

Is there a way or tool to search or know, how many results does google fetch and display with lots of keywords?

I intend to know, how many relevant searches does google display but with thousand of keyword.

Actually, I am researching on the competition on various keywords. If there is a tool or a quick way, other than going to google and typing and then entering the keywords.

Comment: Can you clarify your question.  Are you asking how many results a specific search returns (i.e. 166,000,000 for "webmasters") or are you asking how many times a keyword is searched in Google each month?

Comment: Thanks RandomBen for asking me to clarify. I am asking how many results a specific search returns (i.e. 166,000,000 for "webmasters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no such tool, nor are there any API calls from what I can see you could make to Google Search to return such a fact.